# Compare two file columns (unsorted files)

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

**Input File 1**

```
A1  123 AA
B1  123 BB
C2  44  CC1
D1  12  DD1
E1  11  EE1
```

**Input File 2**

```
A   sad21   1
DD1 124f2   2
CC  123tges 3
BB  124sdf  4
AA  1asrf   5
```

**Output File**

```
A1  123 AA  1asrf   5
B1  123 BB  124sdf  4
D1  12  DD1 124f2   2
```

**Making of Output file**

We check 3rd column of Input File 1 and 1st Col of Input File 2.

If they match , we print it in Output file.

**Note :**

The files are not sorted

I tried :

```
join -t, A B | awk -F "\t"  'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {if ($3==$4) print $1,$2,$3,$4,$6}'
```

But this doesnot work as files are unsorted. so the condition ($3==$4) won't work all the time. Please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -F'/\t/' -anle 'BEGIN{$f=1}if($f==1){$H{$F[2]}=$_;$f++ if eof}else{$l=$H{$F[0]};print join("\t",$l,@F[1..$#F]) if defined$l}' f1.txt f2.txt
```

or shorter

```
perl -F'/\t/' -anle'$f?($l=$H{$F[0]})&&print(join"\t",$l,@F[1..$#F]):($H{$F[2]}=$_);eof&&$f++' f1.txt f2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use `join`, but you need to sort on the key field first and tell `join` that the key in the first file is column 3 (`-1 3`):

```
join -1 3 <(sort -k 3,3 file1) <(sort file2)
```

Will get you the correct fields, output (with [`column -t`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47833/17666) for output formatting):

```
AA   A1  123  1asrf   5
BB   B1  123  124sdf  4
DD1  D1  12   124f2   2
```

To get the same column ordering listed in the question, you need to specify the output format:

```
join -1 3 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3 <(sort -k 3,3 file1) <(sort file2)
```

i.e. file 1 fields 1 through 3 then file 2 fields 2 and 3. Output (again with [`column -t`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47833/17666)):

```
A1  123  AA   1asrf   5
B1  123  BB   124sdf  4
D1  12   DD1  124f2   2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
nawk 'FNR==NR{a[$3]=$0;next}{if($1 in a){p=$1;$1="";print a[p],$0}}' file1 file2
```

tested below:

```
> cat file1
A1      123     AA
B1      123     BB
C2      44      CC1
D1      12      DD1
E1      11      EE1
> cat file2
A       sad21   1
DD1     124f2   2
CC      123tges 3
BB      124sdf  4
AA      1asrf   5
> awk 'FNR==NR{a[$3]=$0;next}{if($1 in a){p=$1;$1="";print a[p],$0}}' file1 file2
D1      12      DD1  124f2 2
B1      123     BB  124sdf 4
A1      123     AA  1asrf 5
>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } FNR==NR { array[$1]=$2 OFS $3; next } { if ($3 in array) print $0, array[$3] }' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Results:

```
A1  123 AA  1asrf   5
B1  123 BB  124sdf  4
D1  12  DD1 124f2   2
```

Comment: @Chronicles: I have tested this. It works fine for me. Are your files both tab-delimited? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Both files are tab-delimited....but when i execute i dont get any error & output as well..

Comment: @Chronicles: This is strange. What version of `awk` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|\(\S*\)\(.*\)|/\\s\1$/s/$/\2/p|' file2 | sed -nf - file1
```